# Windows 11 can not connect to wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-11

Windows made some updates last days and now I am not able to connect to home wifi. My phone is connected but my PC can not. I am sure wifi is ON and I see wifi is connected in task bar dialogue but I have no internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 11 updates are not broken. I have 3 Windows 11 machines here and they all work fine, wireless and all.

**First**, run TCP / IP Reset, restart and test.

> Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
>
> (1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
>
> (2) ipconfig /flushdns
>
> (3) restart the computer

**Second,** download the correct driver for your wireless card, open Device Manager, remove (uninstall) the wireless card.

Then install the new driver, restart and test.

Make sure there are no red or yellow X marks on the device in Device Manager.

**Third,** run DISM / SFC and restart, test.

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

The tests I described are easy to do. If nothing works, the wireless card may have a hardware error.

Test in another location.

Comment: The second one worked for me. Thank you. So I reinstall wifi driver and restart PC. Thank you again.

Comment: Great. Good idea.